# Python) Import multiple modules from same folder

Tags: python

File structure is as follows:

```
app/
  entity/
    schema.py 
common/
  database/
    __init__.py
    conn.py
    crud_wrapper.py
```

In `app/entity/schema.py` I am attempting the following:

```
from common.database.conn import classA
from common.database.crud_wrapper import classB
```

where the **classB** import is returning a "No name crud_wrapper in module common.database".

ClassA imports fine, and the files and classes are all present where they should be with no errors.

Would this be some type of a circular issue, or is there an extra step that is necessary for such an import?

Comment: Maybe include an \_\_init\_\_ file in crud_wrapper?

Comment: Submodules are not automatically imported.  It seems that in `common/database`, you have an `__init__.py` file that imports conn.py, but not crud_wrapper.py.

Comment: It helps if you stop thinking of importing modules from a folder, and instead understand how a *package* is defined *from* the folders in question.

Comment: @chepner I don't think OP would be asking this question if they already understood "how a package is defined from the folders". Why not post an answer?

Comment: Thanks @JohnGordon you were correct. I had to __init__.py for the submodules as well. Perhaps not the best approach, but the laziest way just seems to be adding a blank __init__.py to any directory that might be later imported and then not thinking twice about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding an **init**.py to the `common` directory did the trick. `database` was recognized as a package but `common` was not.

```
app/
  entity/
    schema.py 
common/
  __init__.py # this was added
  database/
    __init__.py
    conn.py
    crud_wrapper.py
```